# Error while run command ffmpeg: Library not loaded: '/opt/homebrew/opt/mbedtls/lib/libmbedcrypto.13.dylib'

Tags: ffmpeg, appium, apple-m1

I want to install appium along with appium doctor. When i run appium-doctor command, there was error in ffmpeg. Then i run commang calling `ffmpeg -version` and i got following error:

```
dyld[89251]: Library not loaded: '/opt/homebrew/opt/mbedtls/lib/libmbedcrypto.13.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/librist/0.2.7_2/lib/librist.4.dylib'
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/mbedtls/lib/libmbedcrypto.13.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libmbedcrypto.13.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libmbedcrypto.13.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mbedtls/3.4.1/lib/libmbedcrypto.13.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libmbedcrypto.13.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libmbedcrypto.13.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      ffmpeg -version
```

im using Apple M1.
[image]

I have uninstall and then reinstall it back using homebrew and still no luck. Anyone can help? Thank you

Answer (score 180):

I fixed by uninstalling both `mbedtls` and `librist` and then reinstalling `ffmpeg` as described [here](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/3505#issuecomment-1719464240)

```bash
brew uninstall librist --ignore-dependencies
brew uninstall mbedtls --ignore-dependencies
brew reinstall ffmpeg
```

Comment: i fixed it by installing the ffmpeg from their site (not using brew)

Comment: Just to be clear, this worked for me, too, although I had to force-uninstall all versions of mbedtls. Thanks!

Comment: This works on macOS Ventura / MacBook Pro M1

Comment: This works for macOS Monterey / MBP Intel

Comment: worked for me mac m1! monteray

Comment: Worked on Mac M2 Ventura!

Comment: worked for me on mac m1 sonoma

Comment: This works on macOS Ventura 13.5 / MacBook Pro Intel

Comment: Worked on Mac M1 macOS Ventura.

Comment: Instead of `brew reinstall ffmpeg` I did just `brew install librist` and that was enough.

Comment: Worked on macOS 14 Sonoma with M1. Thank you.

Comment: Just `brew reinstall ffmpeg` worked for me. Mac M2 / Sonoma 14.2.1 (23C71)

Comment: It works like a charm on Ventura.